# How should i remove ubuntu from boot menu?

Tags: ubuntu

I have deleted ubuntu partition from my laptop (dual booted with W10) then I used AOMEI partition assistant to Rebuild MBR but still I get option to boot into ubuntu on startup and when i click on it it shows me some error screen.

Comment: Do you mean GRUB? It would say so at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit the boot options.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/editing-boot-options) Windows provides the command-line tool BCDEdit.exe, and there are a number of [third party tools](https://alternativeto.net/software/easybcd/) with GUI.

As has been mentioned, back up the EFI Sector Partition (ESP), at the least, or better, image the whole disk before making any change! An error in editing boot options could prevent booting.

[image: Boot Loaders viewed in DiskGenius]
*N.B. Just a view - I do not suggest using a powerful partition editor to change boot order.*

The [easiest way I've found to change boot options](https://superuser.com/questions/1110644/reconstructing-windows-efi-files-in-boot-partition-linuxwindows-dual-boot), though, was in Linux.

- Mount the ESP under Linux (whether from Live USB drive or even an active HDD).
- Browse to `/boot/efi/EFI/`
- Rename the active boot folder.
- Copy another folder to replace it, and change it to the old active folder's name.
- Rename the actual loader inside the folder, changing the .efi file's name to that in the previous active loader.

In fact, on one machine, this was the only way I could get it to boot directly into Linux (the opposite of the issue you have).

[image: boot/efi/EFI]

Answer (score -1):

You have to delete grub (A boot loader [selector for the Os] for linux. You could delete as referred at this [stack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader#429653). But make sure that you have made a backup or even better making a backup and rolling a fresh install of Windows.

Comment: A note for readers: This answer ignores the fact the system is UEFI and not BIOS. It rehashes an old method not applicable for UEFI. Attempting to apply it may have disastrous results.