# How to fix accidentally deleting EFI partitions on dualboot windows 7 and linux

Tags: linux, windows-7, boot, grub, efi

**TL; DR:** How to fix EFI partitions that accidently deleted and cause windows 7 gone from dual boot

**What happend:** So recently im dualbooting windows 7 with linux zorin os (based on ubuntu) and tried to reinstall linux but accidentally deleting the EFI partitions and now only linux show up on grub, i can't boot to windows

**Before Accident:** Windows 7 dualbooted with zorin os, when installing zorin it prompted me to make EFI partitions thinking its just for zorin

**What did i do:**

- Plug linux bootable usb
- Readding (delete and add back) Swap, Root, Home, and EFI partitions
- Error: Can't install, Fatal Error
- Grub Rescue Showed up
- Boot to zorin live sessions
- Run "Repair Boot"
- Repair boot ask to do some command on terminal
- Restart the device

**Result:** Windows Partitions is Intact but can't Boot from grub because memorytest and windows 7 is gone

**Similar Issue:** [Reconstructing Windows EFI files in /boot partition (Linux+Windows dual boot)](https://superuser.com/questions/1110644/reconstructing-windows-efi-files-in-boot-partition-linuxwindows-dual-boot)

Comment: Try the [Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Comment: Im gonna try that later, but do you know how to fix this with "similar issue" links method that i provide? But for windows 7

Comment: With Windows 7, I suppose that this is an old computer. Are you sure that it supports EFI?

Comment: Yes it is an old computer but everytime I plug a bootable USB it has 2 options, normal and UEFI, I'm curious if I install Linux on non-EFI partitions will it fixed since my problem was accidentally wiped EFI partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is actually really simple, just run `sudo update-grub` and grub finally be-able to detect windows boot partitions