# Dual-boot windows 7 + linux black screen during boot

Tags: linux, windows-7, multi-boot, grub

Currently I am encountering an issue with my dual-boot (Windows 7/Fedora) Dell laptop.

Few days ago when i was doing some works using Fedora, the system was suddenly frozen. From then, when I turn on the laptop, the screen remains black until it boots normally into Windows (which is my default os).

When I tried to boot back into Fedora by blindly guessing the grub menu, I ended up every time into Windows. So maybe the option to boot into Fedora has gone for good.

I don’t know what is going on because all I can see is a black screen. Does anybody know what causes this problem, is it possibly due to the corruption of the files from Linux? Does uninstalling the Linux help?

Please let me know if you have any ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: Either something corrupted the firmware, the MBR (unless you use UEFI and GPT, rare with Windows 7, in which case the EFI partition could be corrupted), or there's a hardware fault. If remove the internal drive and try booting from a LiveUSB, what happens?

Comment: I tried to boot to a window 7 rescue usb and the screen remains black. Also, the act of booting from usb is blindly guessing, so the step could be wrong resulted in a different selection from what I expected :(

Comment: Did you disconnect the internal drive first? If not, please do so, and try again. I don't want an MBR or EFI partition to be found except for what's on the LiveUSB.

Comment: Do you mean disconnecting the internal drive using bios? If that the case, it is quite impossible as I can not see what going on when messing around in the dark.

Comment: No, physically disconnect it. I can search for your hardware instructions if you provide the model part number from underneath.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I did try to disconnect the hard drive and the screen also remains black. What should I do now?

Comment: Please turn your last comment into an answer, then come back later and accept it by clicking on the checkmark to help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping guys, after some searching I finally fixed it by clean the cmos pin. It turned out this problem is related to my bios.

Answer (score 0):

You can try boot repair.
The other option is to re-install Fedora, which will re-install the boot loader as well.

What caused the corruption of your files is hard to say. With such a remote debugging, almost impossible.

Your problem is similar to this [one](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?319188-Boot-repair-application-for-Fedora-28).

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/596317/how-would-i-reinstall-the-grub-efi-bootloader-on-fedora-linux) answer should be all you need.

Comment: But do you think that fedora is the cause of black screen during boot? I am afraid that after uninstalling the Fedora, the black-screen issue will still remain and I don’t know whether I can use windows repair cd to fix the boot loader and boot back into windows

Comment: You have to re-install Fedora, not uninstall it. The boot USB should give you an option to re-install.

There is no problem with re-installing Fedora. Its built to dual boot with Windows. The coruption can come from everywhere, including a hardware(hard disk) problem.